# How exactly blockchain node switches to another chain?

Tags: blockchain

AFAIK after block validation node runs all transactions in the block, changing the state (list of UTXOs)

Let's imagine that at some point node realizes that it was on the wrong chain and there is longer chain available, which forked some blocks before.

How does it make the switch? I imagine that it should run all transactions in reverse till the fork happened to restore the state and than replay all transactions in the blocks from the longer chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each node receives individual transactions as well as individual blocks from the network.
It also keeps the most updated blockchain locally.
For every new transaction it receives, the node validates it, and if valid, propagates to its peers.
For every block the node receives, it validates it. The validation includes several steps, among which:
1. checking that the block points to the most recent block in the blockchain (it's preceding block)
2. all transactions included in the block are valid.

A fork is a temporary situation, possible when there are 2 valid blocks (or more) which arrive to a node pretty much at the same time, so the node doesn't know which is the right one. It keeps the first one added to it's local blockchain as the main chain, and keeps the second one as a fork chain (also locally), until a next node arrives, and is added to one of the two. When it happens - the longer chain is chosen to be the main blockchain (at that node!), and the second is kept as a side chain.
All such side chains are kept in the node's memory for some time, until it can be sure they are not relevant anymore (since they are shorter than the main blockchain by several blocks), and then removed.

Comment: I wonder how switching chain works in relation to node state. When block is added, node should run all transactions in the block, changing own state (list of UTXOs in bitcoin). When node switches to another chain, how does it restore state?

Comment: there's a nice explanation with demo here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/how-is-a-wallets-balance-computed#1%20Answer

Comment: By "restore state" you mean recalculate the UTXOs when switching to a side chain.
Keep in mind that a side chain is only a few blocks in delta with current main chain, therefore the calculation of the updated UTXOs (and the "balance") is done only to these delta blocks.

Comment: Correct, so how does this recalculation is implemented? Does node runs transactions in reverse for each block in current chain till it reaches the block where fork happened?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have the picture that anything has to be "rolled back". Yes, it's rolling back, but no calculations with transactions have to be done at all. Here's why:

When node A has N+5 blocks and node B has N+2 block, then all node B has to do is *drop these additional two blocks and take the 5 new blocks from A*.

That's all! Yes, it effectively is rolling back, but nothing has to be run in reverse, because dropping blocks is effectively equivalent to reversing transactions.

Remember that transactions are directed, so they happen only in one direction in time. Meaning: For valid blocks, every non-coinbase transaction in block number N has to have some history in every previous blocks, so block number N *is dependent* on that history, but the opposite is not true. Previous blocks don't depend on block number N, so dropping N won't invalidate them.

Comment: The reason why I am thinking about "rolling back" is list of UTXOs (state, or list of balances). As I understand, after block is added, transactions from the block are executed and change the state (balances change). So I imagine, when node goes back a couple of blocks, it should restore state somehow, to make it the same as it was before these couple of blocks were added and transactions from them were run.

Comment: @eugenekr There's no state that's saved on the blockchain. There are "deltas", which are transactions that take from here and put in there. So to know the balance of an address, you practically have to scan the whole blockchain.

Comment: I used word "balances" loosely. My understanding is that there is a table of UTXOs, unspent transaction outputs. After transaction is run, this table inevitably changes. Prior to running a transaction node checks that it uses UTXOs that are present in the table, otherwise it is invalid. At least this is how it is implemented in bitcoin.

Comment: @eugenekr This table is built by scanning the blockchain. A single address can have multiple UTXOs, so the balance is basically the sum of all these. This still doesn't mean that the last block has a state, but it has a set of UTXOs that can be removed, no problem.

Comment: Correct, but there is still a table of UTXOs, which is also called node state, which is updated after each block is added, so when node goes back a couple of blocks, this table should change?

Comment: @eugenekr I don't believe that such a table exists on the blockchain for many reasons, including that this is redundant information that can be extracted by scanning the blockchain, and I literally never heard of it before. And even if I'm to assume that it exists (which it doesn't), then by some mathematical reasoning you can find that this doesn't change anything, because if adding a block doesn't affect previous transactions, then also removing it doesn't affect them. The state is something block explorers have to deal with, not the blockchain.

Comment: Ah, I see what was wrong with my question. The table of UTXOs does not seem to be a part of blockchain, rather a detail of bitcoin implementation, some kind of cache on top of blockchain. Thanks for clarifying.